# String manipulation with postgres, how to delete a character at the 1st position, if it exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to convert strings in postgres to standardize my strings.

I have 2 small concerns.

1. I have String for example

   ```
    APARTMENT IN
    RESIDENCE OF
    campsite of the
    _beach of_
   ```

I would already like to standardize that each word between a space is put in lowercase and that the 1st letter is an uppercase

```
  Apptment In
    Residence Of
    Camping Of The
Beach Of
```

2. Sometimes I have _ at the beginning and at the end of the string, I would like to remove them, if there is a _ in the 1st and last position.

thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do - split to array of words, use `initcap` to capitalize words and `regexp_replace` to remove underscores and finally merge into a single string again.

```sql
select string_agg(s, ' ') from
(
 select initcap(regexp_replace(unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trim(
' APARTMENT IN RESIDENCE OF 
 campsite of the
 _beach of_'), '\s+', 'x')), '_?([a-zA-Z]+)_?', '\1'))
) t(s);

-- result: Apartment In Residence Of Campsite Of The Beach Of
```

**Edit - make sure the word order does not change**

```sql
select string_agg(initcap(regexp_replace(w, '_?([a-zA-Z]+)_?', '\1')), ' ')
from 
(
 select w 
 from unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trim(
' APARTMENT IN RESIDENCE OF 
campsite of the
_beach of_'), '\s+', 'x')) with ordinality t(w, o)
 order by o
) t;
```

Comment: Reasonable approach but you really should have an `order by` to be sure that the results are guaranteed to be in the desired order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fair enough. Added `with ordinality` to `unnest` and the corresponding `order by`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this. Use

```
\b[a-zA-Z]
```

to detect the first character of each word to change it to upper case.

Check this link out : https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions